# Android RatingBar TextView

Tags: android, textview, ratingbar

how can you create a textview that reacts to the ratingbar stars, for example if a user rate 1 star I want my text view to like say "Your rating is kinda low please leave us some feedback", How do you do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attach a rating listener to your rating bar and check the current rating on the bar, if the condition hits... do what you want:

```
    ratingbar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            float rating=ratingBar.getRating();
            if(rating<2){
              //do your thing

            }

        }
    });
```